# HTMLPurifier not stripping HTML elements

Tags: php, html, css, security, htmlpurifier

Using HTMLPurifier on my input.

The current config is:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'br,img[src],b');
//allow iframes from trusted sources
$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)%'); //allow YouTube and Vimeo
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$clean_update_text = $purifier->purify($dirty_update_text);
```

This correctly strips script tags, but if I input e.g:

```
<h1>Hey</h1>

efsbbwgububgwubgubrubogbowubrugbug

<div class='222'>wgegwegwgw</div>
```

It strips nothing, I want all the text and div content left, but remove all the tags as I give no styling options to users.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you var dump before and after the purify call?

Comment: Tested this with version 4.6.0 and it returned `Hey\r\n\r\nefsbbwgububgwubgubrubogbowubrugbug\r\n\r\nwgegwegwgw` as expected. Can you provide some more information?

Comment: Have you tried posting about it here? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/htmlpurifier